# How to get original forked repository with the github api?

Tags: github, github-api

I am wondering how to get the original repository from my forked repositories.

I am using `https://api.github.com/users/:user/repos?type=forks` to get the list of forked repositories. It returns various links on the forks, but I cannot find how to get the original repository.

Any idea ?

Note: something else that looping over `https://api.github.com/users/:user/events`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can load a list of the forked repositories using just the endpoint you mentioned:

```
curl https://api.github.com/users/:user/repos?type=forks
```

which will return something like the following *JSON* feed (irrelevant informations omitted):

```json
[
  {
    "id": 24328834,
    "name": "repo_name",
    "full_name": ":user/repo_name",
    "owner": {
    }
    ...
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/:user/repo_name",
    ...
  }
  {
    "id": 24328835,
    "name": "repo_name_2",
    "full_name": ":user/repo_name_2",
    "owner": {
      ...
    }
    ...
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/:user/repo_name_2"
    ...
  }
]
```

### EDITED based on @jasonrudolph suggestions

Then, out from the list returned, you pull out the *repo_name* under the *name* element key and use it to construct the repository url, or just refer to the ***url*** element to issue a GET request against as follows:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/:user/repo_name
```

that in return will give you the requested user repository informations (note that is the simplest of queried urls) from which you can retrieve:

- The ***parent*** *JSON* element that holds the repository, from which the issued one was forked, informations including its id / name / url...
- The ***source*** *JSON* element which holds the original repository information, in case the issued repository is a fork of another fork.

Something like the following (here the parent is nothing but the source, i.e. the repository was forked from the original one):

```json
{
  "id": 24328834,
  "name": "repo_name",
  "full_name": "user/repo_name",
  "owner": {
    ...
  },
  ...
  "parent": {
    "id": 354448,
    "name": "repo_name",
    "full_name": "real_owner_name/repo_name",
    "owner": {
      ...
    }
  }
  "source": {
    "id": 354448,
    "name": "repo_name",
    "full_name": "real_owner_name/repo_name",
    "owner": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of extracting the `name` property from the response and using it to manually construct the URL, you can use the `url` property directly (e.g., https://gist.github.com/jasonrudolph/4aa694db242c1cfbf2a5#file-response-json-L116).

Comment: To get the original repository, use the source property (not the parent property).

The parent property contains the *direct* parent of the fork. Keep in mind that the repository might be a fork of a fork. In that case, the parent is not the original repository. For example, given a repo that is a fork of a fork, note the difference between the parent property (http://git.io/vehth) and the source property (http://git.io/vehqJ).

Comment: @jasonrudolph thanks for your notes, I edited the question in regard :)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually much easier to do with the GraphQL API. For example, this is how you query for a list of your own repos showing their name, whether they're a fork and their parent repo URL. You can paste it as-is into the [GraphQL Explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer)

```
query {
  viewer {
    repositories(first:10) {
      nodes {
        name,
        isFork,
        parent {
          url
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "repositories": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "name": "cucumber",
            "isFork": true,
            "parent": {
              "url": "https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby"
            }
          },
          ...
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `parent.url` is the URL of the original repo the fork was cloned from.