# Git: Find Out Url or Name of Repo You Forked From

Tags: git, git-fork

**I'd like a git command to figure out the root repository of my forked repo.**

I forked a repo `parentRepo` and changed the name of my forked repository, `kidRepo`. I did `git remote add origin ...` with the updated name.

Is there a git command (or combo of commands) that I could run from the kid fork to get the name of the repo it was forked from?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're looking for here. Note that your clone of your fork records only the URL of your fork, unless you add additional URLs (perhaps under additional remotes). The hosting system that provides the fork and pull request actions does record, in some way, some sort of linkage back to the repository you forked, but the details vary from one hosting provider to another. (I've also updated the [tag:git-fork] [tag-info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git-fork/info) a bit to provide links to Bitbucket and GitLab, as well as GitHub.)

Comment: @torek I apologize for the lack of clarity. Could you share the details of finding the fork records using Github?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/29549489/1256452 - but I'd recommend testing the case where the fork source repository is deleted, too. Remember that GItHub treats this differently depending on whether the source repo is public or private. There are a lot of corner cases to consider here. (I have no special GitHub insight, I just know they handle these in different ways.)

Answer (score 2):

No. Forks aren't a git concept, and git won't tell you anything about them. They're a GitHub concept, so you could potentially ask the GitHub API about them.